# How to use the createRevokeCollectionAuthorityInstruction to an NFT: "Derived key invalid" error

Tags: solana, metaplex

I'm getting "Derived key invalid" error.
i'm trying to create a transaction that would revoke collection authority.
this is how i setup the instruction :

```
    const metadataPda = findMetadataPda(mintPk); // findMetadataPda() - is imported from '@metaplex-foundation/js' library. 

    const revokeAccount = {
    collectionAuthorityRecord: collectionPk, // this is the key that i can see in metadata object using explorer.solana - inside `collection.key`
    delegateAuthority: authorityKey, // PublicKey of the wallet that created the NFT
    metadata: metadataPda, // this variable is declared above. 
    revokeAuthority: authorityKey, // PublicKey of the wallet that created the NFT
    mint: mintPk, // PublicKey of the NFT 
  }

  transaction.add(
    createRevokeCollectionAuthorityInstruction(revokeAccount)
  );
```

Base on the comments that i added beside each of the revokeAccount attributes, am i using it correctly?

Here is the error that i got from the transaction
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmV9O.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you as using createRevokeCollectionAuthorityInstruction I'm going to assume you are also using the [@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata](https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/metaplex-program-library/docs/token-metadata/index.html) as this is where this instruction creation resides.

[createRevokeCollectionAuthorityInstruction](https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/metaplex-program-library/docs/token-metadata/index.html#createRevokeCollectionAuthorityInstruction) from the docs requires a set of accounts outlined here [RevokeCollectionAuthorityInstructionAccounts](https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/metaplex-program-library/docs/token-metadata/index.html#RevokeCollectionAuthorityInstructionAccounts)

these include

```
collectionAuthorityRecord: web3.PublicKey
metadata: web3.PublicKey
mint: web3.PublicKey
updateAuthority: web3.PublicKey
```

Which differ from what you are currently supplying.

Comment: really weird tho, openning the type of RevokeCollectionAuthorityInstructionAccounts, the attributes is different. https://tppr.me/aa07M . 
if i use those attributes from the documentation i'll get TS errors because of those types